# How to alter single custom field value in views?

Tags: 7, views

I have a view with field Global: Custom Text, which is modified as a link.
I want to change replacement tokens for generating this link, dependent on a value of other field.

Tried to modify this in hook_views_pre_render but I can't find a way to do this.

In hook_views_post_render there are two arrays:

```
$view->style_plugin->render_tokens
$view->style_plugin->row_tokens
```

which contains generated links for every row, but they are not present in pre_render, and changing them in post_render doesn't work.

I've also tried to do that in template_preprocess_views_view_fields but for that specific view this function does not firing (for other views it does), and I don't know why.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
function hook_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  switch ($view->name) {
    case 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME':
      //  override the global custom text field value
      $view->field['nothing']->options['alter']['text'] = 'My custom text';
    break;
  }
}
```

Check the link for more details
[How to insert values into Global custom text field of views programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84458/how-to-insert-values-into-global-custom-text-field-of-views-programmatically)

add nid as field in view and use that field for condition
you can add condition as follows: `if ($nid == '124') {  $view->field['nothing']->options['alter']['text'] = $nid}`

Simple way is to create a new field field_waga which will have field_waga_1 as new name if you check in the view and then you can change the label and override that field with your custom value

```
if($view->result[0]->field_waga[0]['raw']['value'] == '10') {
//here you can create the field to act as custom text field and enter the custom //value
$view->result[0]->field_waga_1[0]['#markup'] = 'alter';
}
```

Comment: This solution changes every field to 'My custom text', I cannot see an option to alter only chosen fields, and to alter a link (if field is modified to display as a link) this way.

Unfortunately I can't use a preprocess_views_view_fields() function, which is mentioned in link you provided, because for unknown (for me ;) ) reason this function is not fired for this specific view.

Comment: you can add condition as follows: if ($nid == '124') {  $view->field['nothing']->options['alter']['text'] = $nid}

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Added condition in this way:
    if($view->result[0]->field_waga[0]['raw']['value'] == '10') {
        $view->field['nothing']->options['alter']['text'] = 'ALTER';
}

If a have a value '10' in first row than all fields 'nothing' has value 'ALTER'.
Not only first, but all rows, unfortunately.

I think it is a global alter and it cannot be used to chosen rows.

Comment: pls check the updated answer

Comment: If I understand correctly, I should remove field "Global: custom text" from views UI, and instead provide programatically created field_waga_1, right?

OK, so this way I have a value but how can I display it in a view?

Comment: No just add a field_waga which you already have again using the add field and then use that field as custom field to input your custom values

Comment: Haha, great idea! Starting from that I achieve exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

As an update to the above answer, I had to set 'alter_text' to TRUE in order for this to work, e.g.:

```
function hook_views_pre_render(&$view) {

  switch ($view->name) {
    case 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME':
    //  override the global custom text field value
    $view->field['nothing']->options['alter']['text'] = 'My custom text';
    $view->field['nothing']->options['alter']['alter_text'] = TRUE;

    break;
  }
}
```