# How can I add a CSS class to a View Field programmatically?

Tags: theming, entities, views

Using template_preprocess_field doesn't work, I assume, because this is a field from a View, not a node.

I've looked at this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/96207) however that only seems to apply to the field value not the markup and styles surrounding it.

For example: The output of the field in markup is currently:

```
<div class="views-field views-field-field-status">
    <div class="field-content">
        Active
    </div>
</div>
```

I'd like to conditionally add classes:

```
<div class="views-field views-field-field-status">
    <div class="field-content my-conditionally-added-class">
        Active
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What type of condition ? e.g?

Comment: @Rupesh a different value of the node

Answer (score 2):

You can add any css class, HTML tag to any field through views admin UI, why don't you add the class from there?

---

**UPDATE**

Because you need add the css class based on some condition, you have to use the following preprocess function. your code is going to be some thing like this (maybe a few modification will be needed )

```
function mytheme_preprocess_views_view_field(&$vars){
     $view = $vars['view'];
    if($YOUR_CUSTOM_CONDITION == TRUE && $view->name == VIEW_NAME)
           $vars['classes_array'] = 'my-conditionally-added-class';
}
```

because you output the content on views you have to use `mytheme_preprocess_views_view_field` function.

For more information visit [Themeing Views field output with Preprocess function](https://www.drupal.org/node/1407442).

Comment: I need the class to be conditional depending on something out of scope

Comment: I updated the answer

Comment: I haven't revisited this as of yet. I mitigated the issue in a less than ideal way but I'll likely look at this again shortly. Cheers.