# Question about adding a field value to a view programmatically

Tags: forms, ubercart

I am having a problem getting a field to print and know it is something I am missing. I am trying to print a product field in a view that is created programmatically. Everything else is working fine, but I cannot pull the item size in to the view. here is the code:

```
 $form['assigned'] = array(
'#type' => 'fieldset',
'#title' => t('Assigned orders'),
'#tree' => TRUE,
'#collapsible' => TRUE,
'#collapsed' => FALSE,
);
$orders = views_get_view('get_drivers_orders');
$orders->set_display('default');
$orders->set_arguments(array('0' => $account->uid));
// change the amount of items to show
$orders->pre_execute();
$orders->execute();
$orders->render();
if ($orders->result) {
foreach ($orders->result as $key => $value) {
  $order = uc_order_load($value->field_driver_id_users_order_id);
  $form['assigned'][$key] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Order #' . $value->field_driver_id_users_order_id),
    '#tree' => TRUE,
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['assigned'][$key]['view'] = array(
    '#markup' => l('View order', 'user/' . $account->uid . '/delivery/' . $order->order_id),
  );
  foreach ($order->products as $product_id => $product) {
    $form['assigned'][$key][$product_id]['attribute'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#title' => t($product->title),
      '#markup' => isset($product->data['attributes']['What would you like']) ? $product->data['attributes']['What would you like'][0] : '',
    );
    $form['assigned'][$key][$product_id]['size'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#title' => t('Size:'),
      '#markup' => isset($product->data['size']) ? $product->data['size'][und][0]['value'] : '', 
    );
  }
  $address = uc_custom_process_get_order_address($order);
  $form['assigned'][$key]['map'] = array(
    '#markup' => l('View map','http://www.google.com/maps?q='.$address.'(tooltip/infowindow title)',array('attributes' => array('target'=>'_blank'))),
  );
  $form['assigned'][$key]['total'] = array(
    '#type' => 'item',
    '#title' => t('Total:'),
    '#markup' => '$' . $order->order_total,
  );
}
```

Here is an image of the krumo of the the view with the products, I do hope someone can help!
   [image: the object from krumo in view] }

I have looked over the proposed solution and it does not fit my use case. I have a view that shows an individual order, that order has products, and those products have all of there values stored in $product->data. I have tried everything to get information from the 'size' field to display in that view and it is not happening. I am not trying to change a value, just display it! I hope this helps everyone help me! :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to insert values into Global custom text field of views programmatically?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84458/how-to-insert-values-into-global-custom-text-field-of-views-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

So the issues was that Krumo pulled that information of its own accord, and the $order object did not have those details. I had to call $product->nid first, query the DB for the field values i needed, and insert them. I ended up with this code, in case it can help anyone!

```
    foreach ($order->products as $product_id => $product) {
    $pid = $product->nid;
    $ps = db_query('SELECT field_size_value FROM field_data_field_size WHERE entity_id = :pid', array(':pid'=>$pid))->fetchField();
    $pp = db_query('SELECT field_pack_value FROM field_data_field_pack WHERE entity_id = :pid', array(':pid'=>$pid))->fetchField();
    $form['assigned'][$key][$product_id]['attribute'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#title' => t($product->title),
      '#markup' => isset($product->data['attributes']['What would you like']) ? $product->data['attributes']['What would you like'][0] : '',
    );
    if(!empty($ps)){
        $form['assigned'][$key][$product_id]['size'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#title' => t('Size:'),
      '#markup' => $ps, 
    );
    }
    if(!empty($pp)){
      $form['assigned'][$key][$product_id]['pack'] = array(
        '#type' => 'item',
        '#title' => t('Pack:'),
        '#markup' => $pp, 
      );
    }
  }
```