# change field value in a view using preprocess_views_view_fields

Tags: views, entities, theming

I'm trying to change the value of a field in a view programatically but i find some problems.

- first is  that even though I created a Global: custom text field which field id is 'nothing', It's value remain unchanged and the value is applied to a new field created at the end of the view.
- Second is that this function creates some errors and drupal send lots of notices:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$wrapper_prefix in include()
>   (line 32 of
>   /my/path/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-fields.tpl.php).
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$label_html in include() (line
>   33 of
>   /my/path/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-fields.tpl.php).
>
> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$wrapper_suffix in include()
>   (line 35 of
>   /my/path/sites/all/modules/views/theme/views-view-fields.tpl.php).

My code is:

```
function real_estast_sub_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
  $view = $vars['view'];

  foreach ($view->field as $id => $field) {

    // change the global custom text content depend on result (node id)
    if ($vars['row']->nid == 1625){
      $vars['fields']['nothing']->content = '666€';
    }else{
      $vars['fields']['nothing']->content = $vars['row']->field_data_field_price_field_price_value."€/noche ";
    }
  }
}
```

What's the problem here? I tried to follow all the steps explained in:

[How to insert values into Global custom text field of views programmatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84458/how-to-insert-values-into-global-custom-text-field-of-views-programmatically)

> Edit:   I soolved the notices form drupal by adding:
>
> ```
>   $vars['fields']['nothing']->wrapper_prefix = '';
>   $vars['fields']['nothing']->wrapper_suffix  = '';
>   $vars['fields']['nothing']->label_html = '';
> ```
>
> But it's like I'm defining a totally new field instead of assigning a
>   value to the existing one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not accessing the fields array correctly, and creating your own additional renderable array within $vars.

Install the [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module if you haven't already and put

```
dpm($vars);
```

at the top of your function.  That will allow you to view the structure of the object on the screen (make sure you're logged in as user 1).

Comment: The problem was that the field was inside a field group so it couldn't be accessed directly. I had to put it outside and It solved the problem.