# change views global text field conditionally

Tags: views

I am trying to either show a text field or hide it depending on the date of another field in a view.
I am trying to use the views_pre_render hook and so far have:

```
function MODULE_NAME_views_pre_render(&$view) {
if ($view->name == 'user_dashboards' && $view->current_display == 'my_tutorials') 
{
    foreach ($view->result as $index => $value) 
    {
        $tutorialtime = strtotime($value->field_field_tr_tutorial_start[0]['raw']['value']);
        if($tutorialtime < strtotime('now'))
        {
            $view->field['nothing']->options['alter']['text'] = '';

        }   
    }   
}
```

}

So I can successfully test whether to show the field or not, however I can't then change the field.  Using the code above changes every global text field in the view.  Is there a way to target just the row in the comparison?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so credit goes to https://www.webfoobar.com/index.php/node/65 which basically gave me the answer.  The working code is as follows:

```
function MODULE_NAME_views_pre_render(&$view) 
{
    if ($view->name == 'user_dashboards' && $view->current_display == 'my_tutorials') 
    {
        foreach ($view->result as $index => $value) 
        {
            $tutorialtime = strtotime($value->field_field_tr_tutorial_start[$index]['raw']['value']);
            if($tutorialtime < strtotime('now'))
            {
                $oldtutorials[] = $index;
            }           
        }
        $view->style_plugin->render_fields($view->result);
        foreach ($view->style_plugin->rendered_fields as $index => &$rendered_result) 
        {
            if(in_array($index, $oldtutorials))
            {
                $rendered_result['nothing'] = '';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be changing $view->result[$index]... instead of $view->field. This will make sure you only change the result in question and not globally.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work; since looking into the problem, it looks like the global text field is treated differently from the other fields e.g. doesn't exist in the $view->result object.  It looks like it is treated as a single object for all rows with replacement patterns been processed elsewhere to give it any conditional display.